# Support with parsing JSON using sed needed

Tags: sed, json

In Home Assistant it is possible to set the state of a switch by executing a command. I am migrating away from my old home automation and it offers a way to get the state, unfortunately not for one switch but for all of them. In the HA forum it was suggested to use sed to parse the json output but I'm not good enough to get it working.

I get the following output:

> {"status": "ok", "version": "3.381", "request": {"route":
>   "/get-status" }, "response": {"preset":0,"time":"2018-03-08
>   09:45","switches":[{"id":0,"type":"switch","status":"**off**"},{"id":1,"type":"switch","status":"off"},{"id":2,"type":"switch","status":"off"},{"id":3,"type":"dimmer","status":"off","dimlevel":0},{"id":4,"type":"switch","status":"off"},{"id":5,"type":"dimmer","status":"on","dimlevel":2},{"id":6,"type":"dimmer","status":"off","dimlevel":0},{"id":7,"type":"switch","status":"off"},{"id":8,"type":"switch","status":"off"},{"id":9,"type":"switch","status":"off"},{"id":10,"type":"switch","status":"off"},{"id":11,"type":"switch","status":"on"},{"id":16,"type":"switch","status":"off"},{"id":17,"type":"switch","status":"off"},{"id":18,"type":"virtual"},{"id":19,"type":"virtual"},{"id":20,"type":"switch","status":"on"},{"id":21,"type":"switch","status":"off"},{"id":22,"type":"switch","status":"off"},{"id":23,"type":"switch","status":"on"},{"id":24,"type":"switch","status":"off"},{"id":25,"type":"virtual"}],"uvmeters":[],"windmeters":[],"rainmeters":[{"id":2,"mm":0.7,"3h":0.7,"favorite":"no"}],"thermometers":[{"id":0,"te":19.1,"hu":49,"favorite":"no"},{"id":1,"te":18.5,"hu":48,"favorite":"no"}],"weatherdisplays":[],
>   "energymeters": [], "energylinks":
>   [{"id":0,"tariff":2,"s1":{"po":497,"dayTotal":1.53,"po+":1379,"po+t":"09:11","po-":0,"po-t":"00:01"},"s2":{"po":0,"dayTotal":50.00,"po+":9,"po+t":"07:13","po-":0,"po-t":"00:01"},"aggregate":{"po":-314,"dayTotal":1.03,"po+":1363,"po+t":"07:26","po-":-1105,"po-t":"08:39"},"used":{"po":183,"dayTotal":2.53,"po+":1463,"po+t":"07:26","po-":39,"po-t":"08:57"},"gas":{"lastHour":0.01,"dayTotal":1.50},"kwhindex":0.00}],
>   "heatlinks": [], "kakusensors":
>   [{"id":0,"status":null,"timestamp":"00:00"},{"id":1,"status":"no","timestamp":"09:21"},{"id":2,"status":null,"timestamp":"00:00"},{"id":3,"status":"no","timestamp":"09:20"},{"id":4,"status":null,"timestamp":"19:31"},{"id":5,"status":null,"timestamp":"00:00"},{"id":6,"status":null,"timestamp":"00:00"},{"id":7,"status":null,"timestamp":"00:00"},{"id":8,"status":null,"timestamp":"00:00"},{"id":9,"status":null,"timestamp":"00:00"},{"id":10,"status":null,"timestamp":"00:00"},{"id":11,"status":null,"timestamp":"00:00"},{"id":12,"status":null,"timestamp":"18:51"}]}}

and I need the one marked in bold. In json I would do something like result.switches.id[0].status and I would like to be able to do the same with sed.
I managed to cut off the first part (up to switches) but every time I try to get something like **{"id":0.*"status":(".*")}.*** I get everything because it matches the last } and not the first it meets.

Any suggestions?

Comment: first of all add your full sed command

Comment: There have been a few questions recently about parsing json using `sed`, and the consensus seems to be that it's the wrong tool for the job. There exists a tool `jq` that was demonstrated in answers to those questions. Thus, I suspect you would do well to look at that avenue instead of using `sed`. A good start might be to perform a web search for "jq json parsing", or search this site.

Answer (score 5):

Suggestion: Don't parse JSON with `sed`.  Use something like `jq` instead:

```
$ jq -r '.response.switches[] | select(.id == 0).status' file.json
off
```

or, if you want to pick the first array element in `switches` and do not care about the actual `id`,

```
$ jq -r '.response.switches[0].status' file.json
off
```

`sed` is good for parsing line-oriented text. JSON does not come in newline-delimited records, and `sed` does not know about quoting rules and encoded entities etc.  To properly parse a structured dataset like this (or XML, or YAML, or even CSV under some circumstances), you should use a proper parser.

As an added benefit of using `jq` in this instance, you get a bit of code that is *easily* modified to suit your needs, and that is equally easy to modify to support a change in the input data structure.

Comment: That's not always a solution - especially when you're writing a "plugin" for another sh script, where only sed/cut/grep are allowed, and no other dependencies are to be made.

Comment: @Evengard Well, I still haven't found a real world situation where installing a JSON parser to parse JSON is not possible.

Comment: Consider this: https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh/wiki/DNS-API-Dev-Guide - the project keeps a minimum amount of dependencies, yet implementing a custom dns api usually (in my case too) involves json...

Comment: @Evengard Sorry, but I can't make heads or tails out of that text. The restrictions on using `cut` etc. but not `awk` seems arbitrary to me. This is not the forum to discuss your particular code. If you have a question about JSON parsing in your codebase, do open a new question about that.

Comment: @Evengard Also note that `jq` is available from https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ as a static binary with no other dependencies.